# Not being able to get data of the sales using sales_order.list using XMLRPC

Tags: java, android, api, magento, xml-rpc

I don't what's wrong with the way i am calling the `sales_order.list` method of the Magento Store.I am getting nil as response from the Magento Store.Actually the Store contains 5 Sales Order.
The Code I am using is as below.
Please some one help me as this a prolonged Problem i am not able to find it's Solution.Thanks in Advance.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient;
import org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Dashboard extends Activity{
    Button loadProductList,loadSalesOrders;
    XMLRPCClient client;
    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
        client = new XMLRPCClient( "http://192.168.1.237/machinetest/index.php/api/xmlrpc");
        mContext=Dashboard.this;
        loadSalesOrders();
      }     

   public void loadSalesOrders()
    {
        Object[] productsGroupList = {" "};
        try 
        {
            productsGroupList = (Object[])client.callEx( "call", new Object[] {Utils.sessionId,  "sales_order.list"});
        }   
        catch (XMLRPCException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        Toast.makeText(mContext, productsGroupList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        for(Object o :productsGroupList) 
        {
        Log.i( "**APP_INFO", o.getClass().getName());
            HashMap map = (HashMap)o;
            Log.i( "Products Keys", "Keys"+map.keySet().toString()); 

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/parsing-the-xmlrpc-webservice-response-in-android/comment-page-1/#comment-7295 may help.

Comment: @B00MER I Appreciate your reply..Found someOne who has interest in this kind of Questions..!!!

The problem of mine is that the Store contains 5 Orders placed already..but when i try to fetch them, i am not getting in the reply that Orders..It gives me nil as response..I don't Understand what's Wrong in my call..please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the same code and it is working for me. Did you get the correct session Id?

Maybe there is some problem in the XMLRPC library. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/issues/detail?id=19) are the two updated classes of the XMLRPC Library: `XMLRPCSerializer.java`  and `IXMLRPCSerializer.java`. Replace these two files in the code and it will work.

```
    String sessionId = "";
    client = new XMLRPCClient(URL);
    try {
        sessionId = (String)client.call("login", "tester", "tester");
        Log.d("MY_XMLRPC_SUCCESS_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
    }
    catch (XMLRPCException e) {
        Log.d("MY_XMLRPCException_MSG", e.getMessage());
    }

    Object[] customerOrderList = null;           
    try {
        customerOrderList = (Object[])client.callEx("call", new Object[]{sessionId, "sales_order.list"});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("APP_INFO", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Yes..i have update those classes so that it will parse the nil response of the Server

Comment: The problem is that i am getting nil response which is wrong..i should get the sales order list.

Comment: Ala yaar...that's the problem..not giving any exception also.Simply when I am toasting the value of productsGroupList ,which i have already initialized to "No data"...it Toast the same value meaning that no data is arriving from the Store

Comment: I have edited the answer.u can varify the code.This code is working fine for me.GOOD LUCk

Comment: I am getting the Image Path,but how to get that Image ??Please contact me when you are Online.

Comment: @krushnakant i use same code but i get this message : HTTP status code:404 !=200  i set adress in localhost for url